# Including mail and institute address for journal publication

Tags: email

here is an example where e-mail address and Institue address are included into a publication format:

https://www.overleaf.com/14982654gxhsgyghrpbk#/56867732/

What it looks like is this (arrows mine):

[image]

The latex code is as follows:

```
\corr{email1@example.com}{FMS}
\corr{email2@example.com}{FS}

\contrib[\authfn{1}]{These authors contributed equally to this work}
\contrib[\authfn{2}]{These authors also contributed equally to this work}

\presentadd[\authfn{3}]{Department, Institute, Country}
\presentadd[\authfn{4}]{Department, Institute, Country}
```

But it is not possible to include the code just like that into a standard article class template - hence my question: what further definition do I need to include? Do I have to create an additional file which defines these macros?

Many thanks